# How to load a json file

Tags: apache-flex, json

I have a json file on my server.

http://myserver/myfile.json

If I type the url into a browser I get a page not found error.

If I set the url of a http service to the path of the json file the httpservice wont load it.

Is it possible to load a json file in this way or does the json file have to be the result of a server page request eg: http://myserver/getjson.php

Comment: Well, i have implemented json format file with .json extension in a flash project, and it worked fine. You are using the sandbox?

Comment: No sandbox, it's all live. It's strange that I cant even load the json file when I type the full url into a browser is it not?

Comment: The problem is this: "If I type the URL into a browser I get a page not found error."  You have a configuration issue on your web server.  There is no way a Flash App can load something from your server that the server itself cannot deliver.  You may have to set a mimetype on the server, or possibly define the 'json' extension as an allowable file.  How you go about doing this depends on your server.

Comment: @flextras thats exactly what I needed to know.  Stick it in an answer if you like and I will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this:

> If I type the URL into a browser I get a page not found error.

It sounds to me like you have a configuration issue on your web server.

There is no way a Flash App can load something from your server that the server itself cannot deliver.

There are two different ways to approach this.  You may have to set a mimetype on the server so the file is recognized.  Or you may have to define the 'json' extension as an allowable file.

How you go about doing either of those things depends on the web server.